# rake db:create and db:migrate work but application hangs

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, amazon-web-services

I'm new to ruby on rails and amazon aws, and am having this issue: I can connect to my database from the command line using this command:

```
mysql -h aaynj18bcvo3e.clqvrttlitbb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u ebroot -p
```

and can also successfully db:create and db:migrate. The issue is that when I try to connect to localhost:3000/users/new my application hangs. I CAN however, see the default rails HTML page when I access localhost:3000/.

I was able to verify that the database and table I created actually exist now.

At this point, I'm not even trying to deploy the app, I just want to be able to connect to the remote database when I'm in development mode.

Please help - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

when you access " localhost:3000 ", it shows all the information about your Database.
and simply if there is a rails icon on the screen, the database connected successfully, 
other wise its not...

This is the simple one to know the database configure and whether connected or not...

Comment: Ok I didn't know that! So I don't see the rails icon, and that confirms that I was unable to connect to the database. But why would I not be able to connect during runtime when db:migrate is OK?

Comment: Which DataBase you are used. I mean where it is specified?

Comment: I've used two, both mysql:

Comment: amazon aws and xeround. I'm getting the same results with both

Comment: Do you mean my database.yml config file? this is what I've got: development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: gignitor_development
  host: instance34049.db.xeround.com
  username: rkotcher
  password:xxxxx
  port: 15188
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Comment: ok, every thing is perfect. Whats the error you got on console when you try to deploy ?

Comment: there are no errors - a connection is never established and the browser hangs